# How to automatically enable chatter feed tracking in sales force?

Tags: managed-package, chatter, chatter-feed-tracking, postinstall, package-install

My requirement is, we have completed our package installation and tested in another org. in that org Feed Tracking is not enabled for some of custom objects.

How can we enable feed tracking for the objects from our package in the install org ?

Comment: Any one help me regarding this issue ........                       How can we enable feed tracking for the objects from our package in the install org ?